# Navigate from App A to App B w/ same credentials - APEX 19.2

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a workspace with 6 apps using the same database and database user accounts. App A is a user manager app that handles user info and user role info for all the apps in the workspace.

I have a 'Change Password' link in the right navbar of all the applications in the workspace that I would like to link to a 'Change Password' page that is in App A.

The intended flow I'm looking for:

- Inside App B (or C, or D, etc...), click the 'Change Password' link
- Take user to APP A's 'Change Password' page w/o user having to log in
  again
- User changes their password and on successful submit is redirected
  back to the home page of App B (or C, or D, etc...)

How would I go about setting something like this up. Also, didn't know if it would be easier to have the 'Change Password' page in APP A be a modal so this way it just overlays the current app I'm in and may be easier then having to do redirects if it was a standard page, but not sure how the modal would behave in this instance.

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As all those applications belong to the same workspace, you're kind of lucky as this *primitive* single sign-on is easy to set up.

Go to every application's

```
- Shared components
  - Authentication schemes (choose the current scheme you're using)
    - Session cookie attributes
      - Put cookie name into ... well, "Cookie name" attribute; 
        let's call it MCRIVERS_COOKIE
```

Link you use to navigate between applications should use `&SESSION.`, e.g.

```
http://myserver:8084/apex/f?p=100:1:&SESSION.
```

and that's it.

---

As of the modal page: try it; I didn't but I *think* it should work. Now that you don't have to enter credentials while moving from one application to another, modal page should just *pop-up* once you call it.

Comment: Much appreciated @Littlefoot

Comment: Quick followup, after some help elsewhere, I found that under the Authentication Scheme settings there is a 'Session Sharing' section that has a 'Type' attribute. If you set this to 'Workspace Sharing' APEX essentially does what you state above for you and adds a '&WORKSPACE_COOKIE.' in the 'Cookie Name' field.  Just FYI...but thanks again

Comment: Thank you too, @McRivers :)

Comment: Correct. It's just a question of what sort of sharing is going on between apps in your workspace. Some people may want different sets of apps sharing, others have most apps in a workspace sharing the same authentication.