# APEX Advisor Errors - 19.2

Tags: oracle-apex

When using the APEX Advisor, how much weight should one put in to fixing everything that comes back? I assume like any tool like this it is a case by case basis, but being new to APEX not sure which are more important than others. For starters, I am just trying to fix the errors.

1. One error I am getting is related to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67724264/navigate-from-app-a-to-app-b-w-same-credentials-apex-19-2). Advisor is throwing a `References with Substitution Syntax` saying that `WORKSPACE_COOKIE` does not exist when setting up a primitive SSO for all apps in the workspace. This seems to be the recommended way to handle this, as APEX adds this for you when you select `Workspace sharing` as option under `Session Sharing` type. Am I missing something? The SSO seems to work as intended across apps in workspace.

[image: Advisor Cookie Error]

2. Also, I am getting the `Invalid SQL statement` error, but the package function referenced by the Advisor validates in APEX and returns data as expected in both app & Toad. Ran page with debug on and no errors where thrown.

[image: APEX Advisor SQL Error]

```
-- 'gdp.gdp_ref_category' package function referenced in APEX
FUNCTION category_list_sql
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS

  vcSQLSource  VARCHAR2(4000);

BEGIN

  vcSQLSource := q'[SELECT 'Edit' edit_url,
                            guidance_category_id,
                            category_description,
                            updated_by,
                            dlu
                      FROM csa.guidance_ref_categories
                  ORDER BY category_description]';

  RETURN vcSQLSource;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    csa.rsn_logger.log_error(p_rsn_app => 'GDP',
                              p_app_loc => 'gdp_ref_category.category_list_sql',
                              p_log_msg => SQLERRM);                               

    RAISE;
END;
```

PS. I know my variable naming convention is not very 'Oracle-like', please overlook and don't judge to harshly. ;)

Comment: The 2nd one, I would wrap that in a ```BEGIN .. END;``` so it is a real block